# change Linux users run time, from a c/c++ code

Tags: c++, c, shell, unix

I want to change Linux users run time, from a c/c++ code. How could I do the same?

Lets say, I am running a c/c++ binary from a Linux user "abc" which is a non root user. Inside the c/c++ code I want to switch over to user a "xyz" to perform a specific task, and then regain the privileges of "abc" back.

Comment: "the same"?? as in... ?

Answer (score 5):

You can't arbitrarily change user ID (unless you're root) as that would be a security hole. There is however, provision to switch your user ID specifically to the user ID of the user that owns the executable in question (as opposed to the user who is *running* the executable). This is the function `setuid()`. For this to work, the program itself must have its `setuid` flag set.

See [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setuid.2.html) and also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) for more information.

Comment: Wikipedia mentions the `setgid`, but just to highlight: do not forget to check the `setgid`. For many applications, changing only group is sufficient.